# Can I force the narrow layout on Twitter's official widget?

Tags: html, css, iframe, twitter

I noticed that Twitter's Embedded Timelines go to a wider layout when they're 318px wide or more. I prefer the narrow version, and was wondering if there is a way to force my widget to keep that layout even when it's wider than 318px.

In Chrome Inspector, the body of the widget has:

```
class="root timeline ltr customisable-border  
twitter-timeline not-touch twitter-timeline-rendered var-narrow"
```

When the widget width goes higher than 318px, it loses the var-narrow class. Can I somehow make that class stay?

Comment: I can't even replicate this.  Can you provide a working example of this?   (When I tried it I couldn't see those classes on the widget body, and the layout wasn't changing in the range of 300 - 400).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. This is how I fixed it:

```
#twitter-widget-0 {
    max-width: 317px !important;
}
```